# Test/Train data set for Graph Network

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a graphical network that I am creating as follows:

```py
g=nx.read_edgelist(data, create_using=nx.Graph())
```

I am trying to create a test and train set for the data. I tried using the below command:

```py
train, test = train_test_split(g, test_size=0.2)
```

but this did not work. Can you please advise how I am suppose to create a test and train set when I have a graphical network.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your task, you can have a try with Stellargraph's `EdgeSplitter` class([docs](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#stellargraph.data.EdgeSplitter)) and scikit-learn’s `train_test_split` function ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn-model-selection-train-test-split)) to do this.

### Node classification

If your task is a node classification task, this [Node classification with Graph Convolutional Network (GCN)](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/demos/node-classification/gcn-node-classification.html#Splitting-the-data) is a good example of how to load data and do train-test-split. It took Cora dataset as an example. The most important steps are the following:

```
dataset = sg.datasets.Cora()
display(HTML(dataset.description))
G, node_subjects = dataset.load()

train_subjects, test_subjects = model_selection.train_test_split(
    node_subjects, train_size=140, test_size=None, stratify=node_subjects
)
val_subjects, test_subjects = model_selection.train_test_split(
    test_subjects, train_size=500, test_size=None, stratify=test_subjects
)

train_gen = generator.flow(train_subjects.index, train_targets)
val_gen = generator.flow(val_subjects.index, val_targets)
test_gen = generator.flow(test_subjects.index, test_targets)
```

Basically, it's the same as train-test-split with a normal classification task, except what we split here is nodes.

### Edge classification

If your task is edge classification, you could have a look at this [Link prediction example: GCN on the Cora citation dataset](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.0rc1/demos/link-prediction/gcn/cora-gcn-links-example.html#Link-prediction-example:-GCN-on-the-Cora-citation-dataset). The most relevant code for train-test-split is

```
# Define an edge splitter on the original graph G:
edge_splitter_test = EdgeSplitter(G)

# Randomly sample a fraction p=0.1 of all positive links, and same number of negative links, from G, and obtain the
# reduced graph G_test with the sampled links removed:
G_test, edge_ids_test, edge_labels_test = edge_splitter_test.train_test_split(
    p=0.1, method="global", keep_connected=True
)

# Define an edge splitter on the reduced graph G_test:
edge_splitter_train = EdgeSplitter(G_test)

# Randomly sample a fraction p=0.1 of all positive links, and same number of negative links, from G_test, and obtain the
# reduced graph G_train with the sampled links removed:
G_train, edge_ids_train, edge_labels_train = edge_splitter_train.train_test_split(
    p=0.1, method="global", keep_connected=True
)

# For training we create a generator on the G_train graph, and make an 
# iterator over the training links using the generator’s flow() method:

train_gen = FullBatchLinkGenerator(G_train, method="gcn")
train_flow = train_gen.flow(edge_ids_train, edge_labels_train)
test_gen = FullBatchLinkGenerator(G_test, method="gcn")
test_flow = train_gen.flow(edge_ids_test, edge_labels_test)
```

Here the splitting algorithm behind `EdgeSplitter` class([docs](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#stellargraph.data.EdgeSplitter))  is more complex, it needs to maintain the graph structure while doing the split, such as keeping the graph connectivity for example. For more details, cf source code for [EdgeSplitter](https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph/blob/develop/stellargraph/data/edge_splitter.py#L32)